# Find character on next line based on postion on current line in regex

Tags: regex

Is it possible to find a character based on the previous line match position in regex?

The matching character does not have a fixed position.

Example. Where the # sign is positioned in the first line would match the character value from the next line.

This would give: 2

```
X#ZEAKBLA
123456789
```

This would give: 7

```
XIZEAK#LA
123456789
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this using regexp? I imagine the regexp could give you the index, and using this index you can directly access the desired character (`string.charAt(index)` etc.)

Comment: It depends on regex flavor. I guess it could be done with recursion which is available in some flavors.

Comment: (Standard) regexes cannot count. It would probably be pretty inefficient with non-standard regexes anyways.

Comment: You could achieve this with IndexOf to find the character, and then just trim the other string to get the value.
[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: It could (also) be done with conditions if there's a finite number of characters.

Comment: I'm aware that I could solve this with code very easily but now I'm, for fun, trying to solve it with only regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a *really* complex version using conditionals:

```
^(?(?=#).*\n(.)|(?(?=.#).*\n.(.)|(?(?=..#).*\n..(.)|(?(?=...#).*\n...(.)|(?(?=^....#).*\n....(.)|(?(?=^.{5}#).*\n.{5}(.)|(?(?=^.{6}#).*\n.{6}(.)|#))))))).*$
```

Basically what it does is to first check for beginning of line and start a multi leveled conditional (if/then/else).

Then follows a test for an increasing number of any characters, starting with 0 (and in this example going up to 7) and after that it test for a match of `#`.

If that is fulfilled, it matches the rest of the line, a line feed, and the same number of *any character* found in the previous test which puts us in the same position as the `#` from the in above.

So now we just capture a single character, which is the result!

If the match with *n* characters followed by a `#` wasn't met, it test the next *else* which has *n*+1 charaters before the `#`, and so on...

If the final test fails, a match for `#` is made (which in a full scale version shouldn't be present) to make the match fail.

Finally, after *closing* the conditional, the rest of the line is matched to avoid continued matching on the current line, if a global flag is used.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lp9r9C/1).

**Edit**

Reduced complexity somewhat by movinf the actual capturing out of the test, to outside it at the end, before matched *rest of line*:

```
^(?(?=#).*\n|(?(?=.#).*\n.|(?(?=..#).*\n..|(?(?=...#).*\n...|(?(?=....#).*\n....|(?(?=.{5}#).*\n.{5}|(?(?=.{6}#).*\n.{6}|#)))))))(.).*$
```

[Here at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/lp9r9C/2)

**Edit2**

Kinda got stuck on this one ;)

Here's an even simpler version. (I've replaced the *index character* with `■` (ASCII 254), mainly to allow for comments within the regex, but also to improve readability (imo).)

```
^               # Match start of line
(?(?=■).*\n|.   # Test if first character is a ■. If not match one of anything
(?(?=■).*\n|.   # Test if second character is a ■. If not match one of anything
(?(?=■).*\n|.   # Test if third character is a ■. If not match one of anything
(?(?=■).*\n|.   # and so on...
(?(?=■).*\n|.   # and so on...
(?(?=■).*\n|.   # and so on...
(?(?=■).*\n|■   # Match a last ! or force a fail (match ■)
.).).).).).).)  # "On the way out" of the match, "eat" characters on the next line
(.).*$          # Capture the character and match the rest of the line
```

As stated in the comments, it matches an arbitrary character after the **match** in all levels removing the need for specific match of each levels characters.

This one also makes it **very** much easier to add levels to the tests.

[At regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lp9r9C/6).

Answer (score 0):

Regex and slice? As EASY solution to implement, for complexity check best answer in this same question, from @ClasG  -amazing

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>     "123#4678911" </p>
<p>    1943215927 </p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "123#4678911"; 
    var otherstr = "1943215927";
    var n = str.search(/#/);
    //returns 3, starts in 0
    var res = otherstr.slice(n,n+1);
    //cut all otherstr between 3 and 4 position
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "position begnng in [0]:"+n;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "number in 2d string: "+res;

}
</script>
```